What is the physics meaning of the gradient of the charge distribution?
In the process of deriving the Jefimenko formula by the Green function method, we encountered a term of the gradient of the charge distribution. I don't know the physics meaning of it or what this term represents. What I know is that it can be transformed into the form of Colomb's law if there is no retarded time, but with a retarded time transformation, I think the technique of integrated-by-part doesn't work, thus far I want to figure out the physics meaning of the gradient of the charge distribution. Or does this term not have any meaning in physics? Thanks for helping!
\begin{cases}
\vec{E}=\displaystyle-\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int\left(\left[\nabla'\rho\right]_{\mathrm{ret}}\frac{1}{R}+\left[\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\vec{j}}{\partial t'}\right]_{\mathrm{ret}}\frac{1}{R}\right)d\vec{r'} \\
\vec{B}=\displaystyle\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\left[\nabla'\times\vec{j}\right]_{\mathrm{ret}}\cdot\frac{1}{R}d\vec{r'} & & & 
\end{cases}

not a dumb question, but what is the source of the equations you show? It differs from the ones in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

If you understand what a charge distribution is, what don't you understand about the meaning of its gradient?

As far as I know, the gradient of the density $\rho(R')$ in a charge distribution is a vector that in each point of that distribution is headed towards the direction in which the charge density increases the most. I'm not sure if this was the physics meaning you were looking for (I am an undergraduate and this is my first contribution to the forum), but I hope it helps!
